# How to produce consistent column names with pivot_wider()

Tags: r, tidyr

When using `pivot_wider()` to expand values from multiple columns, the new column names will be a combination of the names of the columns where names and values were taken from (see example below). When expanding values from a single column, this is not the case – at least by default.

Is there a way to harmonize this behavior using the `pivot_wider()` options? Specifically I would like to have the combined column names also in the case of just a single value-column. I'm not looking for a solution to set the names manually with `names_sep` because I would like to write a function that is agnostic to the number of columns `pivot_wider()` needs to work on. The original variable name (`var1` or `var2` below) should be preserved as part of the column names in both cases.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  iso3c = c("DEU", "DEU", "FRA", "FRA"),
  period = c("pre", "post", "pre", "post"),
  var1 = 1:4,
  var2 = 5:8
)

# names = variable name + period
df |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = period,
    values_from = c(var1, var2)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   iso3c var1_pre var1_post var2_pre var2_post
#>   <chr>    <int>     <int>    <int>     <int>
#> 1 DEU          1         2        5         6
#> 2 FRA          3         4        7         8

# names = period
df |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = period,
    values_from = var1
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   iso3c  var2   pre  post
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 DEU       5     1    NA
#> 2 DEU       6    NA     2
#> 3 FRA       7     3    NA
#> 4 FRA       8    NA     4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: How about something like `df |>  pivot_wider(names_from = period,  values_from = starts_with("var"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `names_glue`:

```
df |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = period,
    values_from = var1,
    names_glue = "{.value}_{period}")

  iso3c  var2 var1_pre var1_post
  <chr> <int>    <int>     <int>
1 DEU       5        1        NA
2 DEU       6       NA         2
3 FRA       7        3        NA
4 FRA       8       NA         4

# or
df |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = period,
    values_from = starts_with("var"),
    names_glue = "{.value}_{period}")

# A tibble: 2 × 5
  iso3c var1_pre var1_post var2_pre var2_post
  <chr>    <int>     <int>    <int>     <int>
1 DEU          1         2        5         6
2 FRA          3         4        7         8
```